# AnimatorListener - onAnimationEnd doesn't work

Tags: android, animation

in my APP I use https://github.com/semanticer/TurriType - it is for "type writer" text animation.

It works (most of the time, could be better....), but my AnimatorListener doesn't work (so onAnimationStart / onAnimationEnd doesn't work too).

In my Activity (not MainActivity) I have this:

```
        Animator.AnimatorListener toastListener = new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            mCardViewChoice1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mCardViewChoice2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    };

    animator = TurriType.write(pageText).withListener(toastListener).into(mTextView);
    mTextView.setText("");
    animator.start();
```

Animation works fine, but I do not receive Toasts, so I can´t work with it.

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: can you try to write logs instead of Toasts ?

Comment: @Rocel Still same, it doesnt get to these methods

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the expected behavior as per the source you provided.

This is the call you make
`animator = TurriType.write(pageText).withListener(toastListener).into(mTextView);`

If you look at line #44 of [TypeAnimationFactory](https://github.com/semanticer/TurriType/blob/master/library/src/main/java/net/semantic_error/turritype/TypeAnimationFactory.java), you'll see it doesn't add the provided animationListener IF there is an interpolator set already.

Finally, if you look at the `TurriType.write(...)` (line #56 [here](https://github.com/semanticer/TurriType/blob/master/library/src/main/java/net/semantic_error/turritype/TurriType.java)) method, you'll see it creates a default "WriteRequest" object with a LinearInterpolator.

Therefore, the animation is going to work, but since your listener is never set, you don't get the callback.

Comment: Oh... I see... Don´t you know, what is the best way to fix it ? Thank you so much.

Comment: I would suggest, without changing too much of the code, add another method in the TypeAnimationFactory called "createAddTextAnimationWithListener" (pretty much a copy of createAddTextAnimation) and provide the listener as a parameter. Finally, call the "animator.setListener..()" there.

Comment: You are awesome, will try. Thank you so much